# Passing URI query param nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a post server listening on port 8081 and sample path.
I want to be able to redirect the entire URI query param the the node service.
How should i do it.

for example i want the following post request url http://exmaple.com/foo/bar?bla=1 to **passed to** http://example.com:8081/foo/bar?bla=1

It looks very simple and straight forward example but just can't get it working, any ide?

```
location ^~ /foo/bar {

                rewrite_log on;
                rewrite ^/foo/bar(.*) /$1 break;
                proxy_pass http://example.com:8081/foo/bar;                 
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `proxy_pass` will not change the request URI (including the query string). The example in your question illustrates **two ways** in which the URI can be changed prior to being sent upstream - by appending an optional URI to the `proxy_pass` statement (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)) or with a `rewrite...break` statement (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite)).

If you remove both, the URI will be sent upstream unmolested and with the query string intact:

```
location ^~ /foo/bar {
    proxy_pass http://example.com:8081;
}
```

Comment: Does it support a POST request either, since your solution didn't worked for me...

Comment: The POST request should be passed transparently. Rereading your question - It is unusual to include URL encoded parameters in a POST request, as the POST request includes a body.

Comment: you are right regarding the post, it's under development and tend to be change in the near future. First i want to fix the reverse proxy isuue i'm having here. I didn't mention but i think it should also be transparent, the server include tls (https)